# Laravel Array output [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4

Tags: laravel

I displayed the data from database using the following code

```
$mani = DB::select('select id from employee');
```

Output :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
               [id] => 1 
           ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
               [id] => 2 
           ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
               [id] => 3 
           ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( 
               [id] => 4 
           ) 
)
```

**I need the following Exact output :**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 2 
    [2] => 3 
    [3] => 4 
)
```

Please share the solution. Thank you

Comment: share you complete sql query?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) instead, so change

```
$mani = DB::select('select id from employee');
```

to

```
$mani = DB::table('employee')->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [laravel-5.2](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.2), then change

```
$mani = DB::table('employee')->lists('id');
```

But if you are using `laravel 5.2` and greater version

```
$mani = DB::table('employee')->plunk('id');
```